# C# PKCS7 Smartcard Digital Signature - Document has been altered or corrupted since it was signed

Tags: c#, pdf, itext, digital-signature, pkcs#7

I try to sign a pdf file using my smartcard (USB token) but encounter `"Document has been altered or corrupted since it was signed"` error when I open the signed pdf file in Adobe. The error is not so descriptive and I'm not sure where to look at because the code seems good to me but apparently it's not..

The code that I use is:

```
var signer = smartCardManager.getSigner("myTokenPassword");
var toBeSignedHash = GetHashOfPdf(File.ReadAllBytes(@"xxx\pdf.pdf"), cert.asX509Certificate2().RawData, "dsa", null, false);
var signature = signer.sign(toBeSignedHash);
var signedPdf = EmbedSignature(cert.getBytes(), signature);
File.WriteAllBytes(@"xxx\signedpdf.pdf", signedPdf);

public byte[] GetHashOfPdf(byte[] unsignedFile, byte[] userCertificate, string signatureFieldName, List<float> location, bool append)
{
    byte[] result = null;

    var chain = new List<Org.BouncyCastle.X509.X509Certificate>
    {
        Org.BouncyCastle.Security.DotNetUtilities.FromX509Certificate(new X509Certificate2(userCertificate))
    };
    Org.BouncyCastle.X509.X509Certificate certificate = chain.ElementAt(0);
    using (PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(unsignedFile))
    {
        using (var os = new MemoryStream())
        {
            PdfStamper stamper = PdfStamper.CreateSignature(reader, os, '\0', null, append);
            PdfSignatureAppearance appearance = stamper.SignatureAppearance;
            appearance.SetVisibleSignature(new iTextSharp.text.Rectangle(0,0,0,0), 1, signatureFieldName);
            appearance.Certificate = certificate;
            IExternalSignatureContainer external = new ExternalBlankSignatureContainer(PdfName.ADOBE_PPKLITE, PdfName.ADBE_PKCS7_DETACHED);
            MakeSignature.SignExternalContainer(appearance, external, 8192);
            Stream data = appearance.GetRangeStream();
            byte[] hash = DigestAlgorithms.Digest(data, "SHA256");
            var signatureContainer = new PdfPKCS7(null, chain, "SHA256", false);
            byte[] signatureHash = signatureContainer.getAuthenticatedAttributeBytes(hash, null, null, CryptoStandard.CMS);
            result = DigestAlgorithms.Digest(new MemoryStream(signatureHash), "SHA256");
            this.hash = hash;
            this.os = os.ToArray();
            File.WriteAllBytes(@"xxx\temp.pdf", this.os);
        }
    }

    return result;
}

public byte[] EmbedSignature(byte[] publicCert, byte[] sign)
{
    var chain = new List<Org.BouncyCastle.X509.X509Certificate>
    {
        Org.BouncyCastle.Security.DotNetUtilities.FromX509Certificate(new X509Certificate2(publicCert))
    };
    var signatureContainer = new PdfPKCS7(null, chain, "SHA256", false);
    using (var reader = new PdfReader(this.os))
    {
        using (var os2 = new MemoryStream())
        {
            signatureContainer.SetExternalDigest(sign, null, "RSA");
            byte[] encodedSignature = signatureContainer.GetEncodedPKCS7(this.hash, null, null, null, CryptoStandard.CMS);
            IExternalSignatureContainer external = new MyExternalSignatureContainer(encodedSignature);
            MakeSignature.SignDeferred(reader, "dsa", os2, external);
            return os2.ToArray();
        }
    }
}
```

The pdf file that I try to sign is [this](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1jiPD3bgzCJRoN3W1kIO59p2EAzDe4YrK/view?usp=sharing).

Temp pdf file that is created after adding signature fields is [this](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1FWXg0pdQjMzTGGLId_HXJuMZchjpSqOC/view?usp=sharing).

Signed pdf file is [this](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1I6hUO8B3fnkgws9Pk1Puti9HjkRJE0Rq/view?usp=sharing).

Base64 format of the hash that is signed is: `klh6CGp7DUzayt62Eusiqjr1BFCcTZT4XdgnMBq7QeY=`

Base64 format of the signature is: `Uam/J6W0YX99rVP4M9mL9Lg9l6YzC2yiR4OtJ18AH1PtBVaNPteT3oPS7SUc+6ak2LfijgJ6j1RgdLamodDPKl/0E90kbBenry+/g1Ttd1bpO8lqTn1PWJU2TxeGHwyRyaFBOUga2AxpErIHrwxfuKCBcodB7wvAqRjso0jovnyP/4DluyOPm97QWh4na0S+rtUWOdqVmKGOuGJ3sBXuk019ewpvFcqWBX4Mvz7IKV56wcxQVQuJLCiyXsMXoazwyDCvdteaDz05K25IVwgEEjwLrppnc/7Ue9a9KVadFFzXWXfia7ndmUCgyd70r/Z+Oviu9MIAZL8GuTpkD7fJeA==`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*I use hex encoding of byte arrays here. Your base64 encoded hash*

```
klh6CGp7DUzayt62Eusiqjr1BFCcTZT4XdgnMBq7QeY=
```

*in hex encoding is equal to*

```
92587A086A7B0D4CDACADEB612EB22AA3AF504509C4D94F85DD827301ABB41E6
```

###In short

Your code hashes the signed attributes twice. Simply don't hash the bytes returned by `signatureContainer.getAuthenticatedAttributeBytes(hash, null, null, CryptoStandard.CMS)` in `GetHashOfPdf` but instead use the authenticated attribute bytes themselves as return value.

###In detail

Analyzing the signature in your example PDF it turns out that

- indeed the hash of the signed attributes is

  ```
    92587A086A7B0D4CDACADEB612EB22AA3AF504509C4D94F85DD827301ABB41E6
  ```
- but the hash in the RSA encrypted `DigestInfo` object of the signature is

  ```
    1DC7CAA50D88243327A9D928D5FB4F1A61CBEFF9E947D393DDA705BD61B67F25
  ```
- which turns out to be the hash of the before mentioned hash of the signed attributes.

Thus, your

```
var signature = signer.sign(toBeSignedHash);
```

call appears to hash the `toBeSignedHash` value again.

The most simple fix would be to replace

```
byte[] signatureHash = signatureContainer.getAuthenticatedAttributeBytes(hash, null, null, CryptoStandard.CMS);
result = DigestAlgorithms.Digest(new MemoryStream(signatureHash), "SHA256");
```

by

```
result = signatureContainer.getAuthenticatedAttributeBytes(hash, null, null, CryptoStandard.CMS);
```

in `GetHashOfPdf` to have only `signer.sign` do the hashing.

###Analyzing such issues

In a comment you asked

> how did you figure all this out :)?

Well, yours is not the first question with a customized iText signing process resulting in errors or at least unwanted profiles.

In the course of the analysis of those questions the first step usually is to extract the embedded signature container and inspect it in an ASN.1 viewer.

In case of your PDF the main result of that inspection was that the signature as such looked ok and that your signed attributes don't contain any variable data.

<sup>*If there had been some variable data (e.g. a signing time attribute) in them, a candidate for the cause of the issue would have been that you build the signed attributes twice, once explicitly in `GetHashOfPdf`, once implicitly in `EmbedSignature`, with different values for the variable data. But as mentioned above, this was not the case.*</sup>

The next step here was to actually check the hashes involved. Checking the document hash is simple, one calculates the signed byte range hash and compares with the value of the `MessageDigest` signed attribute, cf. the [ExtractHash](https://github.com/mkl-public/testarea-itext5/blob/master/src/test/java/mkl/testarea/itext5/signature/ExtractHash.java#L112) test `testSotnSignedpdf` (in Java).

<sup>*The result for your PDF turned out to be ok.*</sup>

The following step was to inspect the signature container more thoroughly. In this context I once started to write some checks but did not get very far, cf. the [SignatureAnalyzer](https://github.com/mkl-public/testarea-itext5/blob/master/src/main/java/mkl/testarea/signature/analyze/SignatureAnalyzer.java#L58) class. I extended it a bit for the test of the hash of the signed attributes making use of the signature algorithm you used, the old [RSASSA-PKCS1-v1_5](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3447#section-8.2): In contrast to many other signature algorithms, this one allows to trivially extract the signed hash.

<sup>*Here the result for your PDF turned out not to be ok, the hash of the signed attributes differed from the signed hash.*</sup>

There are two often seen causes for a mismatch here,

- either the signed attributes are signed with a wrong encoding (it must be the regular DER encoding, not some arbitrary BER encoding and in particular not an encoding with the implicit tag the value stored in the signature has --- even larger players do this wrong sometimes, e.g. Docusign, cf. [DSS-1343](https://ec.europa.eu/cefdigital/tracker/browse/DSS-1343))
- or the hash was somehow transformed during signing (e.g. the hash is base64 encoded or hashed again).

<sup>*As it turned out, the latter was the case here, the hash was hashed again.*</sup>

Comment: It worked, thank you million times. One question though, how did you figure all this out :)? I mean I've seen your solutions in a few other questions too and couldn't figure your ways to approach these signing problems. Any tips to debug/trace these kind of problems?

Comment: Wow, you work so professional. I will check the repo when I have the time too. Take care.